# How can I specify multiple choices in Class-Diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am making a class diagram of a system where a user can act as a student, instructor, or assistant. So far, I've created a user class with the following attributes, and methods, where a user can participate in a single course with a specific role, and also can remove from a particular course. Since, a user can have only one role, I've declared it in square brackets `-Participant: Role [1]`.

However, it says only that a user can have one role, but it does not say the different roles of a user. How can I specify this in a class diagram. Should I make a new `Role` class, or I can specify in the `user` class?

```
USER CLASS:
Attributes:
-username: String
-password: String
-Participant: Role [1]
Methods:
+participate(course: Course, role: Role): void
+remove_user(course: Course): void
+get_average(assignment: Assignment): int
```

Comment: Is something preventing you from accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Role` abstract and then create subclasses for student, instructor, and assistant. That way you can only instantiate one of the subclasses per user.

Alternatively, you can make the `Role` an enumeration, where each enumeration literal is a particular instance of a `Role`. That way you can instantiate one of each `Role` across the entire system: student, instructor, and assistant.

In your system, should all users play the *same* role, or should each user *in* a role have additional information, such as the date the role was assigned to the user? The answer to this question tells you which alternative to choose.

BTW, isn't the limitation of a user being a student, instructor, or assistant, *ever*, a bit *too* limiting? Why couldn't a user play the role of student in one course while playing the role of an assistant in another course?

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Can you be a little more descriptive? Should I make a `Role` class and create 3 more classes which will inherit the `Role` class? In such a case, the `Role` class must have some attributes, does it matter?

Comment: Either 3 subclasses or 3 enumeration literals will work. This question actually touches on a very complex theoretical issue that would probably make your eyes roll up into your head, having to do with predicates and qua entities.